# Is possible to use Bootstrap 4 in CloudCraze?

Tags: bootstrap, cloudcraze, b2b-commerce

Accordingly to the documentation, CloudCraze supports Bootstrap 3. Is it possible to import Bootstrap 4 (both compiled CSS3 and JS)?

Comment: The tag `cloudcraze` doesn't exist and I don't have enough reputation to create it. It would be good if someone adds it.

Comment: CloudCraze is now product of Salesforce. It is renamed to B2B Commerce.

Comment: @OleksandrBerehovskyi That is the reason why I posted it here instead that on SO. However is still commonly known as CloudCraze.

Comment: I just wanted to explain, why I did add one more tag :)

Comment: @OleksandrBerehovskyi Sorry, I realised that my comment was a bit rude. It wasn’t my intention.